# why my animation with html5 canvas is so flickery?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I want to keep the animation as is, my problem is with the flickering of the animation.

if for some reason my question needs more to elaborate on, please let me now and I will explain in more details.

```js
var text = 'got it';
    document.getElementById('mycanvas').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray';
    var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var c = ctx.getContext('2d');

    function ball(x, y, zx, zy, rotation,goldx,goldy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.zx = zx;
    this.zy = zy;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.goldx = goldx;
    this.goldy = goldy;
    this.draw = function() {


    c.beginPath();
    c.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
       c.translate(0, 0.01);
        c.rotate(this.rotation);
    c.fillStyle = 'black';


    c.font="10px corsive";
    c.fillText("$100", this.x, this.y + 10);
    c.strokeStyle = "gray"

    c.rect(this.x, this.y, 24,14);
    c.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.49)';
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
    c.closePath();

    }

    var X = Math.floor(Math.random() *10);
    this.draw1 = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.goldx, this.goldy, 5, Math.PI*2,false);

    c.fillStyle = 'gold';
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
    }

    this.update = function() {
    var b = Math.random() * 500;
    if(this.y  > 510 || this.x > 510 || this.x  < -30) {ballArray.splice(i,1)}

    this.x += this.zx;
    this.y += this.zy;



    if(ballArray.length < 99) {ballArray.push(new ball(this.x,20,this.zx,this.zy, this.rotation))}

    if(x > 350) { this.rotation += 0.00009} else {this.rotation -= 0.00009};
    this.draw();

    if(this.goldy  > 510 || this.goldx > 510 || this.goldx  < 0) {goldArray.splice(j,1)}
    if(goldArray.length < 49) {goldArray.push(new ball(0,0,0,0,0,goldx,goldy))}
    this.goldy += 1;
     

    this.draw1();
     }
     
    }
    var goldArray = [];

    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++){
    var goldx = Math.random() * 500;
    var goldy = Math.random() * 500;
    goldArray.push(new ball(0,0,0,0,0,goldx,goldy));
    }
    var ballArray = [];

    for(i= 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500;
    var y = Math.random() * 500;
    var zx = Math.random() - 0.5;
    var zy = 1;
    var rotation = 0;
    ballArray.push(new ball(y,x,zx,zy,rotation,goldx,goldy));
    }

    function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0,0,500, 500);
     for(j = 0; j< goldArray.length; j++) {
     goldArray[j].update();
     }
    for(i = 0; i < ballArray.length; i++) {
    ballArray[i].update();

     }

    }

    animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Array splice is causing you to skip objects

Your animation is flicking because of a lot of reasons.

The main one being the way you delete a ball and or gold. You call the `update` function from within a for loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
    balls[i].update();
}
```

Then in the update function you test if the ball is out of bounds. If it is you remove it from the array

```
if(this.y > 510) { //  example not your code
     balls.splice(i,1);
}
```

But you ignore the fact that you have just moved all the balls above this one in the array down one index. When the update function returns the ball at `i` has been removed and the next one above it is now at `i`. Then the loop increments `i` and you draw the next ball, skipping a ball.

The skipped ball is not rendered that frame and thus you get the flicker. Same with the gold.

#### Quick fix

There are other problems (many) and to give you a fix will require a complete rewrite.

What you can do is just reset the ball and gold rather than delete it and create another.

Where you have

```
if(this.y  > 510 || this.x > 510 || this.x  < -30) { ballArray.splice(i,1) }
```

change it to

```
if(this.y  > 510 || this.x > 510 || this.x  < -30) {
     this.x = Math.random() * 500;
     this.y = Math.random() * 500;
     this.zx = Math.random() - 0.5;
     this.zy = 1;
     this.rotation = 0;         
}
```

and remove the line

```
if(ballArray.length < 99) {ballArray.push(new ball(this.x,20,this.zx,this.zy, this.rotation))}
```

Do the same for the gold.

that will get you ready for the next problem.

#### Some code notes.

You will still have problems because you have the gold and ball as one object rendering both a ball and gold for each ball and same for each gold.

You need the ball and gold as separate objects, so that the gold does not draw a ball and the other way around.

You should have

```
 function Gold(){ 
     this.draw(){ // draw code
     this.update() { // update code
     ...
 }
 function Ball(){ /* code */
     this.draw(){ // draw code
     this.update() { // update code
     ...
 }
```

And create each

```
 ballArray.push(new Ball( stuff));
 goldArray.push(new Gold( stuff));
```

Also you have need to declare all variables which you have not done for `i`,`j` which thus end up in the global scope and will come back to bug you soon.

Whenever you use a variable it MUST have at some location inside the function a declaration.

eg

```
 function animate(){
     var i;
     var j;
     ... rest of code.
```

#### Oh and more...

but I will leave it there for now.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this helps with canvas but with css animations if you add transform:translatez(0) to the parent container it enables hardware acceleration ad can stop the flicker on complex animations using transform or matrix

Comment: That is an old hack that I doubt is even applicable any more, but besides that the canvas content is independently rendered and is always hardware accelerated (if available and flags correctly set)